# How to show the number of website visitors in my theme

Tags: plugins, php, theme-development, count

I have a column in my website's footer where I show the visitors of today, yesterday and all times which looks like this:

```
<p> Today's Views:   <span> <!--?php here comes the related php code ?--> </span></p><br><br>

<p>Yesterday's Views:   <span> <!--?php here comes the related php code ?--> </span></p><br><br>

<p>All times Views:   <span> <!--?php here comes the related php code ?--> </span></p><br><br>
```

For this reason I've already installed **wp Statistics** plugin and I want o use its functions. But when I try to use one of the functions below I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_statistics_today() in
>   /home/xxxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/xxx/footer.php on
>   line 34

```
<?php echo wp_statistics_today(); ?>
<?php echo wp_statistics_yesterday(); ?>
```

**But when I call `<?php echo wp_statistics_useronline(); ?>` I get the** corrent result.

How can I fix this?

> Please note that **I'm talking about my whole website's view count;
>   not a specific post or page**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need to use for the expected result:

```
<p> Today's Views:   <span> <?php echo wp_statistics_visit('today'); ?>  </span></p><br><br>

<p>Yesterday's Views:   <span> <?php echo wp_statistics_visit('yesterday'); ?> </span></p><br><br>

<p>All times Views:   <span> <?php echo wp_statistics_visit('total'); ?> </span></p><br><br>
```